# Generating non repeating pairs in equal size buckets

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a list of pairs generated from this code

```
int n = listTeam.size();
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
        if (i != j)
            listTeamPairs.add(new Team[] { listTeam.get(i), listTeam.get(j) });
        }
    }
}
```

This will correctly generate these pairs if there are 6 teams.

```
[0 1 , 0 2 , 0 3 , 0 4 , 0 5 , 1 2 , 1 3 , 1 4 , 1 5 , 2 3 , 2 4 , 2 5 , 3 4 , 3 5 , 4 5 ]
```

The problem I am having is to pick these pairs into rounds (buckets) of equal size (three in this case).

First round will become

```
0-1, 2-3, 4-5
```

The problem comes in the second round

```
0-2, 1-3 <- swap order of these matches. 
This leaves only team 4-5 again. Which is not valid.
```

The code that generates the rounds without the invalid entries but not a complete bucket

```
private boolean generateRound(Team[] teamInRound, List<Team[]> roundTeams) {
    Team team1 = teamInRound[0];
    Team team2 = teamInRound[1];
    Optional<Team[]> t = roundTeams.stream().filter(p -> p[0].getName().contentEquals(team1.getName()) || 
                    p[1].getName().contentEquals(team2.getName()) || p[0].getName().contentEquals(team2.getName()) ||  
                    p[1].getName().contentEquals(team1.getName())).findAny();
            if (t.isPresent())
                return false;
            roundTeams.add(teamInRound);
            tmpTeamPairs.remove(teamInRound);

            return true;
}

private void generateRounds(List<Team[]> teams) {

    for (int i = 0; i < listTeam.size() / 2;i++) {
        System.out.println("Reamining pairs");
        tmpTeamPairs.stream().forEach(p -> System.out.println(p[0].getName() + " - " + p[1].getName()));
        if (i == 0) {
            teams.add(tmpTeamPairs.get(0));
            tmpTeamPairs.remove(0);

            continue;
        }
        for (Team[] pair : tmpTeamPairs) {
            boolean b = generateRound(pair, teams); 
            if (b) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

Looking at the proposed answer it does not seem to generate the wanted buckets.

```
scheduled team 0 against team 4
scheduled team 2 against team 3 <-----
scheduled team 5 against team 1
Array order
0
2 <---
5
4
3 <---
1
Lag 5 - Lag3
Lag1 - Lag2 <-----
Lag4 - Lag 6
-----------------------------------------------
scheduled team 0 against team 5
scheduled team 1 against team 4
scheduled team 2 against team 3 <----
Array order
0
1
2 <---
5
4
3 <---
Lag 5 - Lag4
Lag 6 - Lag3
Lag1 - Lag2 <-----
```

Comment: Unrelated, but that `if (i != j)` does not seem to be needed.

Comment: If I = J the team would play itself.

Comment: Sure, but you've got that covered with `for (int j = i + 1;...` already.

Comment: Are you looking for just any partition into rounds? Or a randomized one?

Comment: @RealSkeptic Any would do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another implementation of the round robin schedule.

It returns a list of buckets of pairs. Pairs are just implemented with a `List` though you could create a custom class.

Each bucket is a `Set`, as the order within the bucket doesn't matter, as long as the team pairings are known.

The schedule itself is a `List`, as order does matter in a schedule.

The method is generic, so you can put in the teams as `Integer` or `String` to see if it works well, or use a full-fledged `Team` class.

```
public static <T> List<Set<List<T>>> roundRobin(List<T> teams) {

    int numTeams = teams.size();

    // For a proper league, we only allow even number of teams.
    if ( numTeams % 2 != 0 ) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Number of teams not even " + numTeams);
    }

    List<Set<List<T>>> result = new ArrayList<>(numTeams - 1);


    // Implement the round robin by rotating the right side of the list
    // every time, then pairing opposite teams. Note that the first
    // item is not part of the rotation.
    for ( int i = 0; i < numTeams - 1; i++ ) {
        Collections.rotate(teams.subList(1,numTeams), 1);
        Set<List<T>> bucket = new HashSet<>();
        for ( int j = 0; j < numTeams / 2; j++ ) {
            bucket.add(Arrays.asList(teams.get(j), teams.get(numTeams - j - 1)));
        }
        result.add(bucket);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Thu "trick" here is using `Collections.rotate` on a `subList()` result. This means the rotation is actually reflected in the original list, so we end up with a full list including the frozen team, which makes it easier to loop for the pairs.

The pairs are matched first with last, second with penultimate and so on.

Running this with this `main`:

```
    List<String> teams = Arrays.asList(
                             "Manchester Utd.",
                             "Chelsea",
                             "Tottenham",
                             "Liverpool",
                             "Arsenal",
                             "West Ham Utd." );

    for ( Set<List<String>> bucket : roundRobin(teams)) {
        for ( List<String> pair : bucket) {
            System.out.println(pair);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Results in:

```
[West Ham Utd., Liverpool]
[Chelsea, Tottenham]
[Manchester Utd., Arsenal]

[Manchester Utd., Liverpool]
[Arsenal, Tottenham]
[West Ham Utd., Chelsea]

[Liverpool, Chelsea]
[Manchester Utd., Tottenham]
[Arsenal, West Ham Utd.]

[Liverpool, Arsenal]
[Tottenham, West Ham Utd.]
[Manchester Utd., Chelsea]

[Manchester Utd., West Ham Utd.]
[Tottenham, Liverpool]
[Chelsea, Arsenal]
```

Note that in a real sporting scenario, the schedule also reflects who plays in the home court and who plays away. Here, the frozen team gets to play all its games at home, at least in the first round. If you need to have fair home-away scheduling, you can change the line:

```
bucket.add(Arrays.asList(teams.get(j), teams.get(numTeams - j - 1)));
```

to:

```
Set<List<T>> pair = Arrays.asList(teams.get(j), teams.get(numTeams - j - 1));
if ( i % 2 == 1 && j == 0 ) {
    Collections.reverse(pair);
}
bucket.add(pair);
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want to achieve is to make a tournament plan, with rounds. This can be done using the round robin scheduling algorithm [Round robin scheduling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament)

This works by fixing one of the competitors, let's say 0. The rest will rotated clockwise for producing the new combinations.

Code for achieving this can look something like this:

```
public static void generateRoundRobinPairs(List<Integer> teams) {
    Integer fixedElement = teams.get(0);
    List<Integer> teamsWithoutFirst = teams.subList(1,teams.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < teamsWithoutFirst.size(); i++) {
        List<Integer> toSchedule = new ArrayList<>();
        toSchedule.add(fixedElement);
        teamsWithoutFirst = buildNewRotation(teamsWithoutFirst);
        toSchedule.addAll(teamsWithoutFirst);
        scheduleRound(toSchedule);
    }
}

public static void scheduleRound(List<Integer> teams) {
    for (int i = 0; i < teams.size() / 2; i++) {
        // here create your data structure
        String template ="scheduled team %s against team %s";
        System.out.println(String.format(template, teams.get(i), teams.get(i + teams.size() / 2)));
    }
}

public static List<Integer> buildNewRotation(List<Integer> l) {
    List<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<>();
    newList.add(l.get(l.size() / 2));

    for (int i = 0; i < l.size() / 2 - 1; i++) {
        newList.add(l.get(i));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < l.size() / 2; i++) {
        newList.add(l.get(i + 1 + l.size() / 2));
    }

    newList.add(l.get(l.size() / 2 - 1));
    return newList;
}
```

Comment: Actually called it to early as you can see 5-3 will come in the first two rounds: 
scheduled team 0 against team 2
scheduled team 5 against team 3
scheduled team 1 against team 4 

scheduled team 0 against team 1
scheduled team 4 against team 2
scheduled team 5 against team 3

Comment: Does not help sending the array in [0,1,2,5,4,3].